# Regex to accept only alphabets and spaces and disallowing spaces at the beginning and the end of the string

Tags: java, regex

I have the following requirements for validating an input field:

1. It should only contain alphabets and spaces between the alphabets.
2. It cannot contain spaces at the beginning or end of the string.
3. It cannot contain any other special character.

I am using following regex for this:

```
^(?!\s*$)[-a-zA-Z ]*$
```

But this is allowing spaces at the beginning. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try online on this [site](http://regexpal.com/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For me the only logical way to do this is:

```
^\p{L}+(?: \p{L}+)*$
```

At the start of the string there must be at least one letter. (I replaced your `[a-zA-Z]` by the Unicode code property for letters `\p{L}`). Then there can be a space followed by at least one letter, this part can be repeated.

`\p{L}`: any kind of letter from any language. See [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop)

The problem in your expression `^(?!\s*$)` is, that lookahead will fail, if there is only whitespace **till the end of the string**. If you want to disallow leading whitespace, just remove the end of string anchor inside the lookahead ==> `^(?!\s)[-a-zA-Z ]*$`. But this still allows the string to end with whitespace. To avoid this look back at the end of the string `^(?!\s)[-a-zA-Z ]*(?<!\s)$`. But I think for this task a look around is not needed.

Answer (score 8):

This should work if you use it with `String.matches` method. I assume you want English alphabet.

```
"[a-zA-Z]+(\\s+[a-zA-Z]+)*"
```

Note that `\s` will allow all kinds of whitespace characters. In Java, it would be equivalent to

```
[ \t\n\x0B\f\r]
```

Which includes horizontal tab (09), line feed (10), carriage return (13), form feed (12), backspace (08), space (32).

If you want to specifically allow only space (32):

```
"[a-zA-Z]+( +[a-zA-Z]+)*"
```

You can further optimize the regex above by making the *capturing* group `( +[a-zA-Z]+)` *non-capturing* (with `String.matches` you are not going to be able to get the words individually anyway). It is also possible to change the quantifiers to make them *possessive*, since there is no point in backtracking here.

```
"[a-zA-Z]++(?: ++[a-zA-Z]++)*+"
```

Comment: Correct if you're using Java's `matches()` method, but I would anchor it anyway: `^([a-zA-Z]+\s+)*[a-zA-Z]+$`

Comment: Yes. I assume `matches()` method. Thanks for the clarification. +1.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
^(((?<!^)\s(?!$)|[-a-zA-Z])*)$
```

This expression uses [*negative lookahead* and *negative lookbehind*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to disallow spaces at the beginning or at the end of the string, and requiring the match of the entire string.

Comment: There is an error with your regex, check again the parenthesis

Comment: @Crazenezz Thanks, there was a missing `)` at the end.

Comment: No need to get so fancy.  As the other three responders (so far) have demonstrated, this is a case where correctly matching what you *do* want is sufficient to filter out what you *don't* want.

Comment: @AlanMoore What "fancy" are you talking about? Lookarounds are mainstream these days. An expression *"match a letter, or a space except at the beginning or at the end of the input"* is easy to understand, in addition to being the only solution that does not repeat the character class `[-A-Za-z]`. It's just the syntax that makes it look complicated, but at its core it is trivial.

Comment: What I'm saying is, why use complicated syntax when simple syntax works at least as well?  Once you know what the symbols mean, it's obvious not only that `^[a-zA-Z]+(\s+[a-zA-Z]+)*$` matches exactly what's wanted, but that it does so as efficiently as possible.   According to RegexBuddy, this regex matches the string `"Lorem ipsum tritani impedit civibus ei pri"` in only twenty-two steps, where yours takes **two hundred** and twenty-two!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is there's a ? before the negation of white spaces, which means it is optional

This should work:

```
[a-zA-Z]{1}([a-zA-Z\s]*[a-zA-Z]{1})?
```

at least one sequence of letters, then optional string with spaces but always ends with letters

Comment: No, `(?!\s*$)` is a negative lookahead; it asserts that from the current position (which is the beginning of the string, thanks to the preceding `^`), it is not possible to match zero or more whitespace characters followed by the end of the string.  That's incorrect, but not for the reason you suggested.  *Your* regex will work, but you should get rid of the `{1}` (which has no effect) and add anchors.  The anchors are optional if you happen to be using Java's `matches()` method, but they help signal your intent and they make it easier to port the regex to other flavors.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if words in your accepted string can be seperated by more then one space. If they can:

```
^[a-zA-Z]+(( )+[a-zA-z]+)*$
```

If can't:

```
^[a-zA-Z]+( [a-zA-z]+)*$
```

String must start with letter (or few letters), not space.

String can contain few words, but every word beside first must have space before it.

Hope I helped.

Comment: OP asked `It cannot contain spaces at the beginning or end of the string.`, so if the example like this: `<space><string><space><string><space>` the result will `<string><space><string>`. Your regex just can solve this `<string><space><string>`, if user enter the problem like my example before your regex can't solve that.

Comment: I disagree. OP asked for regex for `validating an input field`. So for data like `<space><string><space><string><space>` matching should return `false`, and thats how my regex works.

Comment: After I read again carefully, maybe my mind set has gone wrong. What I thought is if there is a string like my example above it will check and remove the space before and after the populate string and will show the result (Wondered if OP want to catch even the user input is wrong like `<space>Hello World<space>`).

Comment: I'll re-voted again, but need 2 hours before re-voted. I hope no hard feeling for this :-)